# Why isn't this looping?

Tags: python, python-2.7

## Python 2.7

**Windows 7**

When I type '**play**' once:

```
if(game == "play"):
print("Make sure you type 'Play', CaPS MaTteR! ")
startg()
elif(game == "Play"):
playg()
```

It does what it is supposed to do.  When I type '**play**' wrong two times, instead of looping it just exits.  Searched it on Google but couldn't find anything :/

Code:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
gender = raw_input("What are you, a Boy or a Girl? ")
print(" ")

if(gender == "Boy"):
their = "his "
else:
their = "her "

game = raw_input("Type 'Play' to start. ")

def endg():
print("Hope you had fun! ~Red")

def startg():
game = raw_input("Type 'Play' to start. ")
if(game == "Play"):
 print("Loading. . . ")
 playg()

listq1 = ["A. Quit your job." , "B. Pretend you never saw the stack of papers." , "C.             Kill yourself because you don't feel like playing this game. "]

def playg():
answer = raw_input("You are a programmer, " + name  + ", who hates " + their + "job     very much." +
      " You walk into work to see a huge stack of papers on your desk... What do you     do? \n" + "\n".join(listq1))
if(answer == "A"):
    print("\nYou look around the room and see the flock of miserable people...Your     Co-Workers.  Is working here really worth the stress? ")
elif(answer == "B"):
    print("\nYou pull the over-sized recycle bin out from under your desk.  Just as you start to slide the papers to their impending doom, a fellow co-worker stops to ask what you are doing. ")
elif(answer == "C"):
    endg()

if(game == "play"):
print("Make sure you type 'Play', CaPS MaTteR! ")
startg()
elif(game == "Play"):
playg()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your code:

```
def startg():
game = raw_input("Type 'Play' to start. ")
if(game == "Play"):
 print("Loading. . . ")
 playg()

if(game == "play"):
print("Make sure you type 'Play', CaPS MaTteR! ")
startg()
elif(game == "Play"):
playg()
```

What happens if you mistype "Play" as "play" the first time? Well, it goes to `startg()`. There's the conditional `if(game=="Play")`, but **no else statement** to handle anything but correct input. So if you type "play" the second time, that results in a condition that the program does not account for. So no function is called, and your program proceeds to the end.

By the way, you should introduce an `else` statement to handle all cases in which "Play" is misspelled in some other fashion. Not capitalizing correctly is not the only potential error that you should be prepared to handle.

Comment: I knew it would be something simple, thanks! c: